# How to mount header bracket for garage door opener to concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, garage-door-opener, bolts, anchor

[image]
The anchor of the header bracket securing the garage door opener's rail to the concrete wall above the garage door came loose over time and with vibrations (details in [a previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/186177/what-kind-of-bolt-is-this-securing-the-garage-door-opener-rail-to-the-wall-fac/)).

**What is a good long-term solution for mounting the header bracket**, and allowing for future changes (in case of changing door openers, etc)?

One suggestion is to anchor a ~24" length of a 2x6" beam to the concrete, then screw the header bracket to the beam. Other suggestions are welcomed as well.

For concrete anchors for the above idea, what 1) [**type**](http://www.tatoolsonline.com/uploads/266/safety_data_concrete_anchors.pdf), 2) **embedment depth**, 3) **diameter**, and 4) **spacing/number/pattern** should be used, appropriate for the vibrating load of a garage door opener?

I believe the wall is poured concrete, with 1-2 cm of parging on the surface. I already have on hand some [lead anchors / lag shields, #16-18 x 1-1/2"](https://www.cobraanchors.com/en/our-products/anchors/masonry/lead-anchors.html). I have rotating drills, but not hammer drills.

Comment: Jack has a solid solution for you, but it looks to me like you could mount just to the lumber below if you did it right. You might post a wider shot.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the suggestion. The lumber is the door frame and it's very close to the door, the top of which the rail is resting on in the image above. At the original rail position, the handle on the outside of the door would always get greasy from the chain, so I doubt there is much clearance for moving it lower. Actually, any change has me a bit worried about clearance and adjustment issues.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant to mount a board to the existing lumber, without the need to drill concrete.

Comment: @isherwood Would say a 2x6 by sturdy enough if mounted vertically to the door frame, extending up without being secured at the top to the concrete? Also, it's difficult to see, but the door frame is recessed by 3/4" because of the 3/4" wood trim which was presumably to support the similar thickness of parging on the face of the concrete wall.

Comment: No. I'd put it in horizontally so you can fasten many times to the plate, and I'd use doubled 3/4" plywood for better strength. A 24" x 8" area should do nicely. You could use construction adhesive against the concrete, and you could add bracing at the motor unit if you see movement on the bar axis.

Comment: @isherwood Wouldn't it get torqued loose if just attached at the bottom edge? Aside, even for attaching to concrete, would (doubled) 3/4" plywood be better than 2x6? I've got plenty.

Comment: 1. Maybe, which is why I suggested adequate bracing at the motor. If it can't move there, it can't move at the other end. 2. Yes. Single-ply lumber tends to pop apart on the grain when you do things like running rows of screws into it and mounting dynamically-loaded hardware to it. You could make it work by reinforcing it with screws from the top and bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount a 24" piece of 2x6 up there with four 3-1/2" lag screws and 4 2" lag  shields, one in each corner.Then screw the bracket into that with two 1-1/4" lag screws. Use 3/8" lag screws for the header and bracket.

Center the 2x6 over the hole in the concrete, Screws should be about 1" down and over or 1.4" diagonally from each corner. Washers are a good idea. You're going to need a hammer drill for the concrete since you'll have drill 2-1/4" deep for each lag shield.The drill size will depend on the actual lag shields purchased.

Comment: I take it the 3/8" diameter lead lag shields I have are good enough for securing the 2x6? How far from the corners of the 2x6 and also the concrete edge should they be drilled? Should washers be used under the lag screw heads? Can I make do with a rotating drill for drilling the concrete?

Comment: A 3/8" lag shield takes a 3/8" screw so the diameter of the shield would be approximately 5/8".  The 3/8" lag shields you have would be too small, they'd use a 3/16" screw... too small.  Center the 2x6  over the hole in the concrete,  Screws should be 2 to 3" down and over from each corner. Washers are a good idea.  You're going to need a hammer drill for the concrete since you'll have drill 2 14" deep for each lag shield.

Comment: For screw placement, do you mean 2" to 3" diagonally, i.e. 1.4" to 2" perpendicularly from each edge of the corner? Trying to be mindful of minimum spacing which for 3/8" anchors is 3-3/4" according to the pdf in my question post. Just checked what I have: lead anchor / lag shield (seems used interchangeably, not sure if same thing)  #16-18 x 1-1/2". Suitable or not? https://www.cobraanchors.com/en/our-products/anchors/masonry/lead-anchors.html

Comment: @adatum  Revised to 1.4"  diagonally... I'm not familiar with the shields you have, only the lags I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can still mount it directly to the concrete but I prefer sleave anchors